# Error 404 when I try to delete a user in React application

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, http-status-code-404, error-messaging

i'm currently learning React, i'd like to send a request with axios to delete a user, i'm connected with token. I get an error 404 in console. Any idea why? thanks for your help.

My request in the middleware.js

```js
case DELETE_SUBMIT: {
      axios.delete(
        'http://ec2-54-89-4-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com/projet-mon-potager-back/public/wp-json/monpotager/v1/user-delete',
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${store.getState().auth.token}`,
          },
        },
      )
        .then((response) => {
          store.dispatch(logOut());
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      break;
    }
```

My reducer

```js
 case LOG_OUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        userName: '',
        password: '',
        logged: false,
        nickname: null,
        token: null,
      };
```

My action

```js
export const logOut = () => ({
  type: LOG_OUT,
});
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way for us to help you with this. The 404 status code is returning from the backend, so you should inspect why the backend is sending back a 404 code. Might be you're calling a wrong URI, might be you're trying to delete a user that doesn't exist. Check out if there's any additional info in the response body.

Comment: You need to post more information about your backend since the 404 means that you are trying to send a request to a nonexisting or non handled path.

Comment: thanks for your help, i found the problem, i replaced delete with get and it works